# WPF Canvas Desired size

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have the following control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FooBar.AnnotationControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="400" Width="500" >
    <ScrollViewer Height="400" Width="500">
        <Canvas Height="400" Width="500" Name="ctlCanvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDownHandler" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" >
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ZoomTransform" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>

namespace FooBar
{

    public partial class AnnotationControl : UserControl
    {
        public AnnotationControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void MouseLeftButtonDownHandler( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
        {
           //Do Something
        }
        private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {

            ctlCanvas.Measure(new Size(ctlCanvas.ActualWidth * ZoomTransform.ScaleX, ctlCanvas.ActualHeight * ZoomTransform.ScaleY));
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get the scroll viewer to respond to the scaling of the Canvas.  The call to Canvas.Measure doesn't appear to change the Desired size of the Canvas.  Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Please revise the titles of your two recent questions, titles should 1. not contain tags (like WPF) and 2. describe the problem/ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I seem to have found a solution.  It looks like I can wrap my canvas with another canvas and when I scale it, I simply set the height and width for the outer canvas = initial height and width times the current X and Y scales of the ScaleTransform.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT call Measure on your own. This method is supposed to be called in the layout step, and not somewhere else. Also a RenderTransform doesn't change your Size. The RenderTransform is applied AFTER the actual Layout is done. So you have a scrollviewer that don't need to scroll its content, because its the same size. What you might want is LayoutTransform.

Comment: This doesn't center over the mouse like ScaleTransform does and it doesn't work for Silverlight.

Comment: Thats a different problem. But you are right, LayoutTransform is for transforming BEFORE layout, RenderTransform AFTER layout. But after the Layout the Scrollviewer doesn't know how much you want to scale. What you want to achieve is a bit more complex, i did the same thing for our Diagram control, and i used RenderTransform and made the rest by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is the most primitive element and it simply not designed to work with the ScrollViewer. Use Grid/StackPanel/WarPanel/UniformGrid instead.

Comment: Actually this is not true. Of course it works with Canvas, but not out of the box like someone might expect. If the size of the canvas is bigger than the scrollviewer, then the scrollviewer will scroll the canvas perfectly.

Comment: Canvas should npt be used for any layout elements. Take my word on it.

Comment: Well, I am using this to "draw" arrows, ellipses, lines, etc and zoom in/out.  Can I still do all that with a Grid/StackPanel/WarPanel/UniformGrid

Comment: Dmitry, we layout alot with it and its working fine, and why wouldn't it? Its a simple panel, i agree, but its a panel nevertheless. As long as it returns the proper size to its parent, the scrollviewer, the scrollviewer doesn't care about what child it scrolls. Also we use the Canvas for drawing and displaying huge flow diagrams, So you can take my word on it too ;)

Comment: Well then how do you compell it to return an accurate desiredSize then?  I've read about subclassing Canvas and overriding the method that deals with this.  The problem I have with that approach is this is also a silverlight control and SL4 doesn't wire up the event handlers properly in a subclass.  i suppose I could work around that but...

Comment: Why are you interested in the DesiredSize? Again this is for the layoutstep to know, while Arranging, how much the child wants, the parent still can decide if he gives this amount of size to the child or not. Like the name says the child "desires" this size, but the parent decides the Actual Size.